# Two simultaneous psycopg2 transactions

Tags: python, psycopg2

I'm trying to figure out how to do the following with psycopg2: I have a script that instantiates two connections to two different databases each with its own cursor. The goal is to delete data from a table in database 1 and write the deleted data to database 2. I want to do this in a transactional way that does the following:

1. Begin Transaction: Connection 1 , Cur 1 -> Delete from ...
   returning data Insert Data into database 2 using Connection 2 ,
   cur 2 3) If step 2 is successful commit the Delete From Transaction
   and commit the update transaction

The problem I'm having is that is seems that even though I'm using two separate connections/cursors , one for each database (both with autocommit off) cursor 1 automatically gets committed as soon as an execute with cursor 2 is performed

```
con1 = psycopg2.connect(....)
con1.autocommit= False
cur1 = con1.cursor()

con2 = psycopg2.connect(....)
con2.autocommit= False
cur2 = con2.cursor()

cur1.execute(delete from ... returning)
cur.fetchone().... -> data[]

try:
 cur2.execute(insert ... data[])
 con2.commit()
 con1.commit()
except:
 con1.rollback()
 con2.rollback()
```

The basic idea here is to rollback the delete query on connection 1 if the insert query on connection 2 fails for whatever reason

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: I think the line 7 with the code "cur2 = con1.cursor()" is incorrect, you should use the con2 object.

Comment: Thanks.. Edited. The above code is just pseudo code Illustrating the overall method that's used in the actual script

Comment: Basically you need to do a two fase commit, is described in here, https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-prepare-transaction.html